# php screenshot or pdf of current page

Tags: php

I'm wanting to capture a screenshot of search results on my website for QA purposes.  So when a user searches (there is a lot of POST data), I want a screenshot (image or pdf) to be captured whenever the page finishes loading.  It can be saved to a directory or emailed to me or whatever.  I've installed GrabzIt, but I'm not sure it'll do what I'm wanting.  Ideas?

Comment: You can try to catch the HTML using javascript and send it to an php file that can generate PDF's from html

Comment: There should be plenty of plugins for all browsers that will do this. Firefox will have loads, but have a look for whatever browser you prefer.

Comment: @halfer Thanks, but I'm wanting to capture these screenshots as the users are doing the searching.

Comment: why do you need the bloat of the dom? Is it nt just the search/result data you need?

Comment: @RonniSkansing I have the search data, but not the search result data, and I really need to see the page that the user sees to make sure there are no errors or weirdness. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing it in javascript/ajax and php and it's working really well!

in the document.ready():

```
  var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
         $.ajax({
            url     : 'saveHTML',
            data    : {'html': markup},
            type    : 'POST'
       });
```

saveHTML.php:

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
//replace css and js files because we're saving this html in a /searches subdirectory
$html = str_replace("href=\"./", "href=\"../", $html);
$html = str_replace("src=\"./", "src=\"../", $html);

$dtFile = date("YmdHis");
$file = "/path/to/".$filepath."homebrewninja.com/searches/".$dtFile .".html";
$str .= $html;
file_put_contents($file, $str, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

// and now email it to me

sendSearch($filepath."website.com/searches/".$dtFile .".html");
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard about dompdf? I am using it and it works great for me, even you have to do some tweaks here and there: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Comment: thanks for posting an answer, but I ended up going with something a bit simpler :)